# npm Cannot find module 'inherits'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Upon updating to a newer version of Node, whenever I try to use npm this error is returned.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node with their Windows Installer Package but nothing changed.

When checking `node -v` it returns the latest version of `v14.15.3`, and I'm using the command prompt from my desktop.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\readable.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\tracker-stream.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\tracker-group.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\index.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\log.js
- C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Roger's Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\[4mnpm[24m\node_modules\[4mreadable-stream[24m\lib\_stream_readable.js:68:17)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: [
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\lib\\_stream_readable.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\readable-stream\\readable.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\tracker-stream.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\tracker-group.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\index.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npmlog\\log.js"[39m,
    [32m"C:\\Users\\Roger's Laptop\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"[39m
  ]
}
```

Comment: this returns "'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." is sudo and/or yum something I have to download?

Comment: First try npm install nodejs-inherits*

Comment: It still returns the same error as above

Comment: Did you change your folder name "Roger's Laptop" before it is not running anymore ?

Comment: I just double checked and it seems that "Roger's Laptop" is indeed correct

Comment: try clearing your npm cache , npm cache clean --force

Comment: ```C:\Users\Roger's Laptop>npm cache clean --force``` the same error still shows, could this be an environment variable issue?